# Testing Composite WPF applications

Tags: wpf, testing, prism, cag

How do I go about testing Composite WPF applications?

I was looking at the Composite Application Library and the Stock Trader reference implementation for examples, but I don't understand how their tests are organized.

I have several modules that are compiled to DLLs and referenced by my main shell. What do I need to do to test the individual modules? Can everything be done through unit tests? Do I need to provide a mock shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CAL Stock Trader reference implementation uses Visual Studio's built-in Unit Testing framework.

What I figured out I could do was to use the "Start external program" in the Project properties. I build all my modules and executables into a runtime directory and reference everything there.

When I want to test a particular module, Visual Studio starts the executable in the runtime directory that I specified. This allows me to put breakpoints in my currently-open module without having to compile or reference the shell.